# Ubuntu 20.04: What do I need to install to get "Open With Archive Mounter"

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

In previous versions of Ubuntu when browsing files in the UI it was possible to right click on an archive file and select "Open With Archive Mounter"

However in Ubuntu 20.04 that option does not appear, even if I click "Open With..." and search through the available applications.

What do I need to install or what options do I need to change to get this functionality?

Comment: In Files, I just right click the archive and select "Open With Archive Mounter".. Thinking back, p7zip is usually one of the first apps I install.

Comment: Are you referring to mount an iso image?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I'm trying to mount a zip file

Comment: I can confirm, just recently migrated from 16.04 to 20.04, and I was also looking for "Archive Mounter", but couldn't find any trace of it. Searching for it in Synaptic brings up only the `fuse-zip` package, but this seems to be only for zips... I can't remember whether I was able to mount `.tar.gz` archives on 16.04 or not; so I can't tell whether this is the package that I used to use or not... Anyways, I have installed it. And it *did not* bring back the "Open with archive mounter" context menu item. When choosing "open with other application, Archive Mounter is not on the app choice list.

Comment: However, the default Archive Manger app seems to be good at navigating and opening files within the compressed stuffs.